# How can I create an object of an a class that is present on an external jar in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, annotations

I am currently learning Spring Boot and encountered this problem. I have a simple class that deals with authentication and it is present on an external jar(Aunthenticaion.class). The fields of this external class are simply username,password and a url and it gives me an authentication based on these credentials. All I want to do is make an instance of this class (by passing these credentials)at compile time, because my application throws build error when this username,password and url are not set.

package org.Authentication;

public class Authentication{

```
String username;
String password;
String url;


public String getUserName() {
    return username;
}
public void setUserName(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String GetToken(String username,String password,String url) {
    return TokenService.getToken(username,password,url);
}
}
```

Above was the Authentication class that is present on the external Jar. I get that there must be similar type of questions that are already present but I apologize in advance and your replies will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Well, you call its constructor like for any other class: new Authentication(). Then you call its method(s) on the created object. What is the concrete problem? It's just a class, like any other class (except it doesn't respect the Java naming conventions, and its has fields that don't serve any purpose).

Comment: That said, no this code isn't even valid Java code. You don't pass the types of the arguments when calling a method: `TokenService.getToken(username, password, url)`. Is that what your question is actually about? If it is, I strongly advise to familiarize with Java with stuff much simpler than a Spring Boot app, because Spring Boot is quite a complex beast.

Comment: TokenService.getToken(username, password, url) gets the token in a form of a string. I have ommitted a couple of imports and an instance of this TokenService class in this code sample. I did not intend to pass the type of arguments, it is simply a result of careless copy and paste.

Comment: OK. Then what is the concrete problem?

Comment: In another sample application, someone has created a bean in an xml file like <bean id="authentication" class="org.Authentication"> <property name="username" value="xyz" /> <property name="password" value="***" /> <property name="url" value="sample.com" /> </bean> and had autowired it. But I want to achieve the same functionality without using xml.  Note that authentication is an external dependency

Comment: So your question is how to make a Spring bean without using XML. You'd do that using an @Bean annotation in a configuration class. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-basic-concepts

Answer (score 1):

You can create object in two ways either in static or in dynamic

**Static**

```
Class<?> clazz = Authentication.class;
// static call
Method getUserName = clazz.getMethod("getUserName"); 
String uname = (Stirng) getUserName.invoke(null /* static */);
```

**Dynamic**

```
Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
Object instance = ctor.newInstance();
Method print = clazz.getMethod("GetToken", String.class, String.class, 
String.class);
print.invoke(instance, uname,passwd,url);
```

Comment: I tried making an object following similar steps but my build always fails and the error message is the username is not set.  I believe I have to make the object available during compile time.

Comment: In another sample application, someone has created a bean in an xml file like     `<bean id="authentication" class="org.Authentication">
  <property name="username" value="xyz" />
  <property name="password" value="***" />
  <property name="url" value="sample.com" />
        </bean>`   and had autowired it. But I want to achieve the same functionality without using xml. Thank you.

Comment: @Yourfavouritenoob. I hope this link is helpful, http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Spring-Without-XML-The-Basics-of-Spring-Annotations-vs-Spring-XML-Files